# Emscripten: Linking library to project

Tags: ffmpeg, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to build a small project that uses ffmpeg library to WebAssembly, with use of Emscripten. Before that, I tried it out by transpiling some simple program from C into Wasm and it worked fine, but that time I was not using any additional libraries.

For C++ I'm working with **Visual Studio** and **FFmpeg** I linked in project's "Properties" as follows:

1. all .h header files I placed in "include" catalog and I added it as "Additional Include Directories" in "C/C++" section
2. all .lib and .dll.a (for example avcodec.lib or libavcodec.dll.a) files I placed in "lib" and added as "Additional Library Directories" in "Linker" section

All includes and the program itself works fine, so now I was trying to prepare a Wasm module with Emscripten with the same same command that I used earlier, but already knowing that is not going to work:

```
em++ cut_video.cpp -Os -g1 -L lib -I include -s WASM=1 -s FORCE_FILESYSTEM=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s EXPORT_ES6=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s "EXPORT_NAME='Editor'" -s "ENVIRONMENT='web'" -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_doubler', '_cut_video', '_cut_video1']" -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0  -s ASSERTIONS=1 --bind -o cutter.js
```

I added the "-I include" parameter which is suppose to be pointing to the same header files, that I mentioned above, and it seems to be fine for Emscripten, because the initial error was solved by it.
Emscripten already found out the problem with functions from ffmpeg library, so I added "ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0" just to see what will happen when I will add this module to front-end app. Obviously it end up with error "missing function: av_register_all", which is first ffmpeg function within my code.

All explanations that can be helpful I found really unclear for me, because generally I'm not working with C++ or Linux environment, so I'm not fimilliar with Makefile or so.

Is there a way, basing on what I described and how my project was prepared with Visual Studio, to tell the Emscripten to use those pre-build .dll.a or .lib files of FFmpeg for my app? Or how should I modify my project to make it acceptable for Emscripten?

Edit: Since **cut_video.cpp** file is quite big, maybe it's a better idea to just paste here a [link to this file on github](https://github.com/mspas/Video-editor/blob/master/cut_video.cpp) instead of the big block of code.

Comment: You should avoid to link static libs not generated by Emscripten, you should make a step back, and compile the ffmpeg static libs with Emscripten with emmake make ( of course you need the ffmpeg source code for this) and after that link these static libs. I will provvide a detailed answer if you need.

Comment: can you post the cut_video.cpp file?

Comment: @kalwalt thank you for your response! I added a link to cut_video.cpp file to the post above. I will try to read more about emmake and how to use it but if you will have some spare time to give me a better idea of it, I will be really gratefull.

Comment: I will take a look at, thank you!

Comment: I think, as i said, you should compile FFmpeg libs with Emscriten, but it require a lot of works. But you can look at https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm-core and https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm

Comment: Oh I've also found a [instruction](https://itnext.io/build-ffmpeg-webassembly-version-ffmpeg-js-part-1-preparation-ed12bf4c8fac) made by the author of this lib. So I will try to follow it, and maybe adopt it to my idea. Thanks. ;)

Comment: Yes there is a tutorial, read carefully until the end, you will avoid a lot of issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### FFmpeg and Emscripten

Build the FFmpeg libs with Emscripten is not an easy task, but you can follow the [ffmpeg.wasm](https://ffmpegwasm.github.io/) tutorials:

1. [Introduction](https://jeromewu.github.io/build-ffmpeg-webassembly-version-part-1-preparation/)
2. [Build with Emscripten](https://jeromewu.github.io/build-ffmpeg-webassembly-version-part-2-compile-with-emscripten/)

Read carefully until the end all the tutorial, because there are so many issues that can arise.

### Note

I suggest to you to start with the FFmpeg and Emscripten version used in the tutorial and look at the [build-ffmpeg.sh](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm-core/blob/n4.3.1-wasm/wasm/build-scripts/build-ffmpeg.sh) script. The script itself export a wasm file with a main function

https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm-core/blob/85f0e51d9a94447a3b3481c7a4794c2eb9abbfee/wasm/build-scripts/build-ffmpeg.sh#L22

```
-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="[_main, _proxy_main]"  # export main and proxy_main funcs
```

that is, the main function from fftools/ffmpeg.c. This will help you a lot.

### Useful resources

Note that in the Emscripten docs there is a list of C/C++ libraries/project ported to WASM/Javascript, there are some FFmpeg projects see [utilities](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Porting-Examples-and-Demos#utilities)

Happy coding!

Comment: what is proxy_main, I searched the source code, it only appear at build-*.sh, where does it come from?

Answer (score -1):

the option returns linking error :
emcc: error: undefined exported symbol: "_proxy_main" [-Wundefined] [-Werror]
does the USE_PTHREAD option generate the proxy_main(...) function to abstract the main(...) ?

-s USE_PTHREADS=1                             # enable pthreads support
-s PROXY_TO_PTHREAD=1                         # detach main() from browser/UI main thread
-s INVOKE_RUN=0                               # not to run the main() in the beginning
-s EXIT_RUNTIME=1                             # exit runtime after execution
-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="[_main, _proxy_main]"  # export main and proxy_main funcs